# define a lambda function in single line using semicolons in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, syntax-error

In python3, following works:

```
print(3); print(5)
```

However following gives a syntax error due to semicolon:

```
(lambda key: (print(3); print(5)))
```

Why is that, and is there a way to write a lambda function in single line (I intend to pass it as a short argument, without defining the function elsewhere)

Comment: that was easy... should I delete the question or mark this as an answer?

Comment: i suspect this is an XY problem but impossible to know without more context...

Comment: What are you using this for? Is this simply so that you can `print` items across multiple lines in one line of code?

Comment: I tried to see what is passed as key argument when I use `min(tupleList, key=(lambda key: print(key), key[1]))`, so thats the context nothing too serious. posted here because I thought its a quick syntax question that hasnt been asked yet

Comment: You can just use `def`, and it'd be way more readable. You don't have to define it "elsewhere" per se, you can use a nested `def` if need be.

Comment: somewhat dirty (but maybe ok for debugging I guess) `min(lst, key=lambda x: print(x) or x[1])`

Comment: Why are you using a lambda to print()?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am passing lambda function as an argument o key for `min` and I just wanted to confirm if key arguments were what I thought they were. So this isnt related with the code I am working on, just wanted to see what it is, and know why ; worked normally but not in lambda functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existing answers cover the "how?" of the question, but not the "why". Which is to say, *why* doesn't `lambda: print(3); print(5)` work? The answer is in the language specification.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda:

> Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create anonymous functions. The expression `lambda arguments: expression` yields a function object. [...] Note that **functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain statements** or annotations.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=semicolon#simple-statements:

> A simple statement is comprised within a single logical line. Several simple **statements may occur on a single line separated by semicolons**.

`print(3); print(5)` contains a semicolon, so it is a collection of simple statements. But a lambda can't contain statements. So a lambda can't contain `print(3); print(5)`.

---

So why does `(lambda key: (print(3), print(5)))` work? It's because `(print(3), print(5))` is not a statement. It's an expression: in particular, it is a tuple literal (formally, a [parenthesized form](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) whose expression list contains at least one comma), whose first element is a [call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-call) to `print` with argument 3, and whose second element is a call to `print` with argument 5. All of this is a single expression, so lambda accepts it without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda function and use it in a single line. But its not with semicolons.

Define lambda in brackets and pass arguments immediately after that using brackets:

```
(lambda x,y: x+y)(6,4)
```

This will give output 10.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible option:

```
f = lambda x, y: print(x, y, sep='\n')
f(3, 4)

# 3
# 4
```

Comment: Curious, on my machine `help(print)` gives `print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`.